# JSdoc for objects defined in different file

Tags: node.js, jsdoc

I have function in file A.js which accepts an array of say, Person which is defined in other file, entities.js.

**A.js**

```
function put(persons) {
}
```

**entities.js**

```
function Person(name) {
   this.name = name;
   this.age = 10;
}
```

Now, in A.js, when I am writing JSdoc for method put, what should I put in type for persons? It should be ideally be {Person[]} but I don't know how should I reference since that exists in different file. There is one way I could require entities.js file like :-

```
var Person = require('./entities').Person;
```

and then if I do {Person[]}, it works but I just want to import the definition just for JSDoc? Is this the only way to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to think this looks hideous, but you can do this `@param {module:someModule/SubModule~ExportedClass}`:

### MyType.js

```
/**
 * A dummy type module
 * @module myModule/MyType
 */

/**
 * Dummy type
 */
class MyType {
    /**
     * Creates a MyType
     * @param {Number} foo Some var
     * @param {Number} bar Some other var
     */
    constructor(foo, bar) {
        this.foo = foo;
        this.bar = bar;
    }
}

module.exports = MyType;
```

### Some code that uses `MyType`

```
/**
 * Test
 * @inner
 * @param {module:myModule/MyType~MyType} c The caption
 */
function test(c){
    console.log(c);
}
```

This would give you something like this:

[image: JSDoc output]

---

The key thing to note is that you need to be really explicit with JSDoc.  The documentation provides a note detailing how to specify that certain objects or exports are part of a module using the `module:MODULE_NAME` syntax here: [CommonJS Modules: Module identifiers](http://usejsdoc.org/howto-commonjs-modules.html#module-identifiers).

> In most cases, your CommonJS or Node.js module should include a
>   standalone JSDoc comment that contains a [`@module`
>   tag](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-module.html). The `@module` tag's value
>   should be the module identifier that's passed to the `require()`
>   function. For example, if users load the module by calling
>   `require('my/shirt')`, your JSDoc comment would contain the tag
>   `@module my/shirt`.
>
> If you use the `@module` tag without a value, JSDoc will try to guess
>   the correct module identifier based on the filepath.
>
> When you use a JSDoc
>   [namepath](http://usejsdoc.org/about-namepaths.html) to refer to a
>   module from another JSDoc comment, you must add the prefix `module:`.
>   For example, if you want the documentation for the module `my/pants`
>   to link to the module `my/shirt`, you could use the [`@see`
>   tag](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-see.html) to document `my/pants` as
>   follows:

Here is another example using your exact files with the additional `@module` declarations:

### entities.js

```
/**
 * Person Module
 * @module Person
 */

/**
 * Creates a person
 * @class
 */
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = 10;
}

module.exports = {
    Person: Person
};
```

### A.js

```
var Person = require("./entities").Person;

/**
 * Module for putting people somewhere
 * @module A
 */

/**
 * Does something with persons
 * @param {module:Person~Person[]} persons Some people
 */
function put(persons) {}

module.exports = {
    put: put
};
```

### Exact File Example Render

[image: JSDoc Rendering with Exact Files]

Comment: Can you tell specifically for my case what would be? I tried, {module:entities~Person} but it did not become link when I generated JSdoc

Comment: @Chacha Yes, please see my newest edit.  Let me know if you have additional questions.

Comment: Does this still work? JSDoc is frustrating at best, and the solution here is the closest to what I've been trying to find...but it doesn't seem to work - even if copy/pasted exactly.